# Fetch for refresh token not working (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, fetch-api

Here I am again. I'm trying to do a fetch to ask the API for a refreshed token based on previous stored token in localStorage. It gives error 400() and I still don't know why. It is required for the previous token to go on the body of the POST request.

Any help is acceptable, I feel really lost... I've been with this issue for days already...

```
    fetch(url + '/api-token-refresh/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }, body: JSON.stringify({
            token: localStorage.getItem('token')
        })
    })
```

I think the problem comes from when I store in localStorage, because on the Request Payload I get

> token: "{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo0LCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InJpY2FyZG8uY2Fycm9sYUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1MzMxMTY2OTQsImVtYWlsIjoicmljYXJkby5jYXJyb2xhQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsIm9yaWdfaWF0IjoxNTMyNTExODk0fQ.sS3kuC8o51Rix505BFy9nT5w9iygNaKViGq_fVtVChk"}"

Qhat means I don't get just the token...

If you need anything else, just ask and I will add to the question.

Comment: does `console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'))` return the expected result?

Comment: pls show what is written with error

Comment: Yes, the console.log returns `{token: "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo0LCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InJpY2FyZG8uY2Fycm9sYUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1MzMxMTYzNDMsImVtYWlsIjoicmljYXJkby5jYXJyb2xhQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsIm9yaWdfaWF0IjoxNTMyNTExNTQzfQ.uJyuPpv3Ck88jr1LMArcGsN7S3sa6bdQKllocp84Ybg"}` @Signo

Comment: `POST APIurl/api-token-refresh/ 400 ()` @ShubhamAgarwalBhewanewala

Comment: @SofiaRibeiro if that's the result of `console.log(localStorage.getItem('token'))` then you probably just need to replace `body: JSON.stringify({
            token: localStorage.getItem('token')
        })` with `body: JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('token'))`, since localStorage returns already a key/value pair you don't need to recreate the body

Comment: have you tries this request using something like curl or Postman to check that the token is valid on serverside?

Comment: Yes, I tested on postman and everything went well @qais

Comment: Now the Request Payload is correct `{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjo0LCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InJpY2FyZG8uY2Fycm9sYUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1MzMxMTczNTIsImVtYWlsIjoicmljYXJkby5jYXJyb2xhQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsIm9yaWdfaWF0IjoxNTMyNTEyNTUyfQ.28_H__P0QOyc86FPZJxiyZmFJ7VYWDy1c5WY4LYy82g"}` but the fetch isn't working yet @Signo

Comment: @SofiaRibeiro do you still get a 400 error? Is there any detail in the error response?

Comment: @Signo Yes, I do. No, the error is only what I told before...

Comment: @SofiaRibeiro if the request body is correct now can you try by adding to the headers `'Accept': 'application/json'` ?

Comment: @Signo I had that before, and now I add it again and it didn't make any difference

Comment: @Signo In the response from the Request has this `{"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str."]}`

Comment: See my answer @Signo and thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using JSON.stringify and the token was going on the Request has a string, has soon has I changed the body, the status changed to 200. Thanks for who helped!

```
fetch(url + '/api-token-refresh/', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }, body: (localStorage.getItem('token'))
})
```